# What happened to `fsused` and `fssize` in `lsblk`?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, system, versions

Why are these columns (`fsused` and `fssize`) not available in `lsblk`?

On my Manjaro system I can see that:

```bsh
$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fsused,fssize,size,fstype,uuid
NAME MOUNTPOINT LABEL FSUSED FSSIZE   SIZE FSTYPE UUID
loop0
     /var/lib/s       146,8M 146,8M 146,8M squash 
loop1
     /var/lib/s          98M    98M  97,9M squash 

...

$ lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.36.1
```

works just fine. However on my Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) this is somehow not the case (anymore?):

```bsh
$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fsused,fssize,size,fstype,uuid
lsblk: unknown column: fsused,fssize,size,fstype,uuid

$ lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.31.1
```

Comment: Please show the version number for both OSes - run `lsblk --version` on both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is contained in [package version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=util-linux).

This functionality [was introduced](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/Documentation/releases/v2.33-ReleaseNotes#L373) in util-linux 2.33.

This means that versions prior Ubuntu 20.04 LTS do not have the `FSAVAIL,FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSUSE%` flags.